# Calculating the Growth Percentage between two periods

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a single table of complains and the date they were submitted.
What I have to do is, given the start and end dates of two periods, I have to calculate the percentage of growth between them.

For example:

- Q1 (January - March) Claims = 200
- Q2 (April - June) Claims = 400

To calculate growth:

- (Present - Past) / Past * 100
- Growth percentage =  (400 - 200) / 200 * 100 = 100% Growth

The information I have to extract from that report that is claims have grown 100% between Q1 and Q2

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM complaints WHERE submit_date >= start_date_period_1 AND submit_date <= end_date_period_1) AS q1_claims,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM complaints WHERE submit_date >= start_date_period_2 AND submit_date <= end_date_period_2) AS q2_claims,
  (SELECT ((q2_claims - q1_claims)/q2_claims * 100) AS 'Percentage Growth')
FROM complaints;
```

but does not show the output in the correct form. It shows a record for every date in the given period. How can i fix the query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your original query, you were mixing aggregate (i.e. `COUNT`) and non-aggregate columns, forcing MySQL to give you a result set containing a record for every row.  Try using this query instead:

```
SELECT 
  ((q2.claims - q1.claims)/q2.claims * 100) AS 'Percentage Growth'
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS claims FROM complaints WHERE submit_date >= start_date_period_1 AND submit_date <= end_date_period_1) AS q1,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS claims FROM complaints WHERE submit_date >= start_date_period_2 AND submit_date <= end_date_period_2) AS q2
```

Comment: I didn't know you could put SELECT statements in FROM! And your query is so neat. Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer after the time limit :)